# how to add logo to background in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-organization

The Unreal Engine Trello has the Unreal logo in the background.
https://trello.com/b/gHooNW9I/ue4-roadmap

How does one put a logo in the background color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a paid-for [Trello Gold](https://trello.com/gold) or [Business-Class account](https://trello.com/business-class). Then you can upload your own background images, as well as do a bunch of other things.

Comment: I do have trello gold. However, I just want to add a logo to an existing background color. The functionality you mention will change the entire background image.

Comment: The logo is simply part of a flat background image: https://trello-backgrounds.s3.amazonaws.com/510c52e608ef68960a00036e/d757b4c93a194e7c4af1ae7bcc8144a9/roadmap_bg.png

Answer (score 0):

1. If you find a really good background
2. You do not necessarily have to pay
3. Such as the gray one with the unreal icon
4. Go to the link suggested in the question: https://trello.com/b/gHooNW9I/ue4-roadmap
5. Simply click, "show the menu" of the public board ~(top right)
6. Click "... more"
7. Click "copy board" - and you get your own private with the background.
8. Now archive the cards you do not want and you are good to go.
9. You now have the background image for your board and can make whatever board you would like.
10. But you cannot upload your own particular image for background. that action needs gold. so instead, you must take from someone who has set background picture from gold account.

Experience: been on the app for two days. - great stuff!

Comment: good background boards you can copy for free:

https://trello.com/inspiringboards